# Problem with subdomain on nginx

Tags: nginx

I have a problem with subdomain on nginx server.
In our project, we need create different urls for different store views. For example:
main url: **site.com**
url for english store: **site.com/en**

I implemented next solution: 
in root folder created new directory "en", where moved index.php and .htaccess files.
For English store view for secure and unsecure section I add new Base Url and Base Url link configuration http://site.com/en/.   For other 3 leave http://site.com/.

Because our live site on nginx server I add for each store new option:

```
location /en {
  #rewrite ^/en.html /en/ permanent;
  index index.php;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /en/index.php;
}
```

Everything works good, but when I make search on site (like **site.com/en/catalogsearch/result/?q=opening+hours**)it doesn't work. I made some researching and examined that in Mage_CatalogSearch_Helper_Data file in getQueryText() action array **$_GET is empty**.
I think that I have wrong nginx configuration, **because on local machine (on Apach)everything works good**. Can anybody help me, please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you, @Serpyre, that is a neat summary and one I shall remember.

Answer (score 2):

Solved this problem. Solution was next: need to rewrite

```
location /en-us {
    #rewrite ^/en-us.html /en-us/ permanent;
    index index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /en-us/index.php;
}
```

to

```
location /en-us {
    #rewrite ^/en-us.html /en-us/ permanent;
    index index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /en-us/index.php?$args;
}
```

Just  add **?$args** part in last line and $_GET params will be visible.
Hope, this solution help somebody.